# Build "Chat" and "Activity Feed" features from microsoft teams using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

The "Chat" capability in microsoft teams allows the user to start a chat, read and write messages further to that chat.
The "Activity Feed" capability shows a feed of the latest messages that the user is part off.

I have a question about microsoft teams graph api support - With the current set of graph api’s, is it possible to build a capability like “Chat” and “Activity Feed” that we see in Microsoft teams?

Comment: You can [build a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create) which allow user to chat with and you can optionally send [activity feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed#rest-api-sample) for 1:1 conversation. Could you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a chat,you can read the content of the Teamwork's chat thread section.The URL like this:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/chatthread

If the answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer

Comment: The documentation link that you shared clearly states that the Future API releases will support ability for reading/writing direct chats between users. It doesn't seem to help then.